# How to find out data type in IQ

Tags: sap-iq

I want to make a select statement that shows me all user tables, columns, data types and data length of the selected columns.

I have done it already in ASE but the system tables in IQ are different and I can't join the necessary tables to get my select. In ASE the code looks like this:

```
select so.name as 'table name', sc.name as 'column name', st.name as 'data type', sc.length as 'data  length'    
from sysobjects so
inner join syscolumns sc on so.id = sc.id
inner join systypes st on sc.usertype = st.usertype
where so.type = 'U'
```

I used the `usertype` as a join key to get what I want, but in IQ the `syscolumn` and `systypes` can't be joined like that, anyone know how I can get it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  t.table_name,
  c.column_name,
  d.domain_name,
  c.width,
  c.scale
FROM SYS.SYSTAB t
JOIN SYS.SYSCOLUMN c
  ON t.table_id = c.table_id
join SYS.SYSDOMAIN d
  on d.domain_id = c.domain_id
where t.creator <> 0 --sysobjects type 'S'
and not exists (select * from sys.systab tv 
                where tv.creator in (2, 22) 
                and tv.table_id = t.table_id) --2/22 sysobjects type 'V'
```

Comment: Thx for you answer, it does exactly what i wanted, but i figured it out myself later that day 

`select T.table_name , C.column_name , C.scale , C.width , D.* from syscolumn C key join systable T key join sysdomain D where (T.table_name = 'table_name') order by T.table_name, C.column_name`